# how to validate the simple php login form with the mysqli query?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

this  is my php code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}\\check connection
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]); $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con$_POST["password"]); \\get the input values                                              
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")\\check for the form method
{
    session_start();\\start the session 
if(!empty($_POST["username"]))
{
    if(!empty($_POST["password"]))
    {\\ if the username and password is not empty,then execute the query

    $res=("SELECT * FROM personal WHERE username='".$username."' password='".$password."') or die(mysqli_error());\\get the row value accoring to the input username and password
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1)\\to check the number of rows, if it is 1 then execute the loop
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $user = $row['username'];
        $pass = $row['password'];\\assign the row values to the variables
        if ($password != $pass)
        {
       echo"Please Register your details";
        } \\if not match
        else{
            header("Location:home.php");
        }\\else goto home page
    }
    else{
        echo"Enter the Valid Password";\\error message
        }
}
else {
    echo"Enter the Valid Username";\\error message
}
}
mysqli_free_result($res);
}
mysqli_close($con);\\close connection
```

and my html form is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>
<title>Sign-In</title>\\title of the page
</head>
<body id="body-color">

<div id="Sign-In">

<fieldset style="width:30%"><legend>LOG-IN</legend>\\field setup

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">\\open form tag

Username: <br><input type="text" name="username"  maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $username;?>"><br>\\get user name

Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50"value="<?php echo $password;?>"><br>get the password

<input type="submit" value="Log-In">\post the details
</form>\\close form

</fieldset>

</div>

<p>If you are not a exsiting user go to <a href="reg.php">Register</a></p>\\ link to the next page

</body>

</html>\\close html file
```

Comment: where did u set the $_POST params to variables?

Comment: From the code highlighting you can see that you messed the quotation marks on line one.

Answer (score 3):

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for stuff like this. It's absolutely unclear what you're actually asking, therefore I just refactored your PHP code and hope this might help.

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);

if ($username && $password) {
  try {
    $connection = new \mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `personal` WHERE `username` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $hash);
    $found = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($found === true && password_verify($password, $hash)) {
      session_start();
    }
    else {
      echo "We either don't know the username or the password was wrong.";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $connection->close();
  }
  catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    echo "An error ocurred while communicating with the database, please hang in there until it's fixed.";
  }
}
else {
  echo "Please enter a username and a password.";
}
```

- Use exceptions instead of checking the returned values of each function and/or calling additional methods.
- Use object oriented code for better readability.
- Use prepared statements to ensure that no SQL injection is possible.
- Use PHP's built-in [password functions](http://php.net/ref.password).
- Use PHP's built-in [filter functions](http://php.net/ref.filter).
- Don't tell the client what really went wrong (unknown username and/or wrong password).

Answer (score -1):

Don't know what you want but i think theirs error in your code.

```
  $res="SELECT * FROM personal WHERE username='".$username."' password='".$password."'";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql));
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
   {

    }
```

You declared sql query in string but never fired it.
If that was causing problem then this should solve it.