# Cant login user with hash password previously created with signup query

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I'm still such a noob. I'm trying to login a user using a hash_password previously created in signup query. I've been looking around here but I guess I don't understand how it works and need help understanding it.

**signup.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

// set parameters and insert in users table  
$date_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$user_level =$_POST['user_level'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email =  $_POST['email'];

//Store $hashedPassword in the database under the password column.
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// prepare and bind // users table
$user = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email,created) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)");
$user->bind_param("ssss", $username,$hashedPassword, $email,$date_now);
$user->execute();

}
```

**login.php**

```
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

     $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
       $hashedPassword = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and  password = '$mypassword'";


      $result = mysqli_query($db,$hashedPassword);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1 && (password_verify($mypassword,$hashedPassword))) {

         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: user/adminhome.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }

}
```

Comment: you need [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) and going about it all wrong.

Comment: obviously I know. I don't understand it. I saw `password_verify()` in the manual but just can't grasp the notion here.

Comment: You're comparing a hashed password with a plain text password.  It's mathematically *very* unlikely that they would be the same.

Comment: Explain this. You are checking `hashedPassword` against password in **plaintext**. How on earth will it match ?

Comment: Also, why do you have *two* SQL queries?  You can select more than one field in the same query.

Comment: You also shouldn't be escaping the (plain text) password because that would probably do more harm than good. Where a possible valid password like `Fred'sBar&Grill\_here` would be invalidated by `real_escape_string()` and reduced to something like `Fred\'sBar&Grill\\_here`. `password_verify()` takes care of that.

Comment: @David: I thought the password was not hidden but stored in the hash?

Comment: @SebastianFarham: Yes, you should store the hashed password.  But when you're comparing the user's password with the stored password you need to hash the user's password before the comparison.  Hashing the password makes it *different*.  So you need to perform the same function before comparing it.

Comment: @David: I believe this will create a totally different hash no?

Comment: @SebastianFarham: I think you're missing the concept entirely here.  When you "hash" a string, it creates a completely different string which (ideally) can't be reversed into the original string.  That's why you store a hashed password, so that the original password can never be recovered (because that would be a bad thing).  Now, when you want to compare the password during login, you can't compare the supplied password directly with the hashed password.  Because they are different.  By design.  So you have to hash the supplied password, *then* compare them.

Comment: @David *"you need to hash the user's password before the comparison"* - I think you got that backwards. When verifying a plain text with a hash in db, you `password_verify()` against the plain text with the hash in db.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Well, that's essentially what `password_verify()` does, hash the supplied password and perform the comparison.  Which the OP *should* be using, but even the manual attempt here would still have to manually hash the supplied password before comparing.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: So I would need to do something like `if (password_verify($mypassword, $hashedPassword))`

Comment: @David Ok, I guess I misinterpreted that. Yes, that's what they should be using, as I stated in [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263208/cant-login-user-with-hash-password-previously-created-with-signup-query#comment71683804_42263208), but they seem to not grasp "how" to do it. Personally, the php.net website should have better examples in that manual in regards to using it with a database. Maybe they're waiting on (more) "User Contributed Notes"?

Comment: @SebastianFarham Essentially, yes. Plus, make sure that the password column's length is indeed 60+ in length, otherwise your query may fail on you "silently" once you have it going. If it isn't, then you'll need to start over with a new hash.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: yes well I did write this  `if($count == 1 && (password_verify($mypassword,$hashedPassword)))` and now getting `mysqli_fetch_array parameters expected boolean given` and `mysqli_num_rows() parameters expected boolean given` so im guessing I need to rewrite the entire script lol. I'm lost right now. I was proud of this. It worked before I tried to make my app more secure.

Comment: @SebastianFarham This answer may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/a/24629536/1415724

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I'm doing the exact same as  the guy in the answer except I do not use a try-catch block.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I guess learning by example is not something SO encourages here am I right? `:-D`

Comment: @SebastianFarham To a certain extent; yes. Sometimes, people spend too much time in trying to help and fix code, where a total rewrite would most likely take less time. But then, that could also lead to other issues where there could be issues with the person's database/structure at hand, so we don't always know what it looks like, the column types, lengths, etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I did delete one query and made this query      `$hashedPassword = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and  password = '$mypassword'";` this eliminates the boolean problem. Then edited this `$result = mysqli_query($db,$hashedPassword);` But no password ever match. Learning by example would be useful. I do not understand.

Comment: @SebastianFarham See this (accepted) answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42253542/1415724 and the related question. That's another example you can base yourself on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Replace your login.php code with the following. I have made few tweaks to your code. Hopefully it will work. Make sure to check the differences carefully. :)

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = $_POST['password'];           // no need to real escape this

    // query for getting hashed password for the $myusername
    $hashedPasswordQry = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername'";


    $result = mysqli_query($db,$hashedPasswordQry);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row['active'];

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count == 1 && (password_verify($mypassword, $row['password']))) {

        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
        header("location: user/adminhome.php");

    }else {

     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";

    }

}
```

Comment: Probably because this answer makes no attempt to identify the problem or describe the solution.  "Here's some code to copy/paste without understanding it" generally doesn't make for a quality answer.

Comment: @David Thanks. Understood

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password);
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and  password = '$hashedPassword'";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Comment: I just tested this and the username and password are not matching. You see if I replace `$hashedPassword` with the hash from the database i'm able to login. It does not work dynamically.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. On third line, I have changed `$hashedPassword = password_verify($password, $hashedPassword);` to `$hashedPassword = password_verify($password, $password);`. Could you give it a try?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` should not be used for the password. [Read my comment about this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263208/cant-login-user-with-hash-password-previously-created-with-signup-query?noredirect=1#comment71683910_42263208). @RendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: Plus, it's not the `id` that should be selected, it's the password. Plus, `$hashedPassword = password_verify($password, $password);` will fail; don't use the same variable and it should be checked against the user input and the hash in the database.